# Can't print Yoast meta description into page template (syntax error, unexpected '.')

Tags: php, plugin-development, templates, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Here is the relevant portion of my page template code:

```
$yoast_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true);

function my_service_template_footer_data() {
    echo "<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
    '@context': 'https://schema.org/',
    '@type': 'Service',
    'serviceType': ' " . get_the_title() . " ',
    'description': ' " . $yoast_meta; . " ',
    'provider': {
      '@type': 'LocalBusiness',
      'name': '...',
  'address': {
      '@type': 'PostalAddress',
      'addressLocality': '...',
      'addressRegion': '...',
      'postalCode': '...',
      'streetAddress': '...'
    },
    'providerMobility':'...',
    'telephone': '...',
    'image': '...',
    'PriceRange': '...',
    'serviceArea': [{
        '@type': '...',
      'name': '...',
      '@id': '...'
      }]
  }
}
</script>";
        
}
```

When I save the file I get this error from WP_DEBUG:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/260255.cloudwaysapps.com/hyubphmutk/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/functions.php on line 99
There has been a critical error on this website.**

How can I re-use the Yoast meta description? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed an unwanted `;` (semicolon) in your function (try to look at line 99 in the `twentytwentyone-child/functions.php` file) which likely is the cause to the syntax error. So just remove that `;` and the error would be gone:

```php
function my_service_template_footer_data() {
    echo "<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
    '@context': 'https://schema.org/',
    '@type': 'Service',
    'serviceType': ' " . get_the_title() . " ',
    'description': ' " . $yoast_meta; . " ', // remove the ;
    ...
```

But that variable is not actually defined or that it is out of scope in `my_service_template_footer_data()`, so you should move/copy the variable into that function, and use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`, like so:

```php
function my_service_template_footer_data() {
    $yoast_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true );
    ...
```

However, your JSON data is not in the valid format, e.g. property names should be wrapped in *double* quotes, so for example you would use `"description"` instead of `'description'`. Also, you must properly escape the property values which can be done via the [`wp_json_encode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/) function (an enhanced version of the native [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function in PHP).

So having said that, try this which uses the `?>HTML here<?php` syntax and not `echo 'HTML here'`:

**Update:** The above JSON-encoding functions will enclose the return value in double quotes, so don't do `"<?php echo wp_json_encode( ... ); ?>"`, i.e. do *not* include the quotes (`"`).

```php
function my_service_template_footer_data() {
    $yoast_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true );
    ?>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Service",
    "serviceType": <?php echo wp_json_encode( get_the_title() ); ?>,
    "description": <?php echo wp_json_encode( $yoast_meta ); ?>,
    "provider": {
        "@type": "LocalBusiness",
        "name": "...",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "...",
            "addressRegion": "...",
            "postalCode": "...",
            "streetAddress": "..."
        },
        "providerMobility":"...",
        "telephone": "...",
        "image": "...",
        "PriceRange": "...",
        "serviceArea": [{
            "@type": "...",
            "name": "...",
            "@id": "..."
        }]
    }
}
</script>
    <?php
}
```

PS: If `get_the_ID()` isn't giving you the correct ID, try using `get_queried_object_id()` instead, and then use `get_the_title( get_queried_object() )`. ( And you can validate your structured data [here](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results).. :) )

Comment: Thanks Sally! I will give this a try. I abandoned this approach to use something less desirable, but I will see if I can keep going now on this track. =)

Comment: Sure, take your time 

Comment: I will check `wp_json_encode` - I have been starting to try out json_encode but didn't realize there was a `wp_json_encode` ... hah!

Comment: Ok I tried implementing this. I got the values (yay), but also printing an extra set of quotes around those values! Please see screenshot here: https://imgur.com/jmKYuDS thanks.

Comment: PS Sally - You can check my code here (which is living in my functions.php file): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxDoS.png

Comment: Figured it out - the `wp_json_encode()` seems to have been adding its own quotes, in addition to the ones in the JSON. I removed `wp_json_encode()` and got just one set of quotes. :)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry my bad! But please don't remove it - see the "Update" in my answer. :)